# RewriteRule and RedirectPermanent conflit (adds query string)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mod-alias

All of my `RedirectPermanent` rules add a query string to the URL. That unwanted query match the redirected rough URL redefine by `RewriteRule` as followed :

```
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)-(.*)$ index.php?page=page&id=$1 [L]
```

This rule works just fine to create that kind of URL :

```
https://example.com/page-320-enfants
```

The 301 redirections are defined as followed :

```
RedirectPermanent /page-320-enfants /page-2028-pour-les-invitees
```

Problem : this adds a query string to the newly created url :

```
https://example.com/page-2028-pour-les-invitees?page=page&id=320
```

I tried to use `RewriteRule` (old URL to new URL) instead of `RedirectPermanent` as recommanded in old questions but it has the exact same effect.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE :**

As adviced, I tried to use `RewriteRule` placed before the common rule itself :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect Permanent #
RewriteRule ^page-2028-pour-les-invitees$ page-320-enfants [R=301,L]

# Common rules #
...
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)-(.*)$ index.php?page=page&id=$1 [L]
...
```

This attempt does not trigger at all. Could the problem be in the syntax ?

Comment: What did your RewriteRule attempt look like, and _where_ in the existing rewrite setup did you put it?

Comment: Yes, the `RedirectPermanent` rule will add the query string from the earlier rewrite. "I tried to use RewriteRule (old url to new url) instead of RedirectPermanent as recommanded in old questions but it has the exact same effect." - That sounds like you are seeing a cached response from the earlier `RedirectPermanent` (301s are cached persistently by the browser). If the correct `RewriteRule` is placed _before_ the above rewrite it would work as intended. If you placed it after then it wouldn't do anything since the URL-path will not match.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure where I should reply. Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `RedirectPermanent` (mod_alias) directive will add the query string from the earlier rewrite. The `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) directive is processed first, despite the apparent order of the directives, so internally rewrites the request to `index.php?page=page&id=320`. The `RedirectPermanent` directive is processed later, but looks at the originally requested URL-path only (not the rewritten URL) so triggers a redirect, but the *new* query string from the internal rewrite is then appended (any query string on the original request would otherwise be appended).

If you are already using mod_rewrite for internal rewrites (and possibly other redirects) then you *need* to use mod_rewrite throughout to avoid such conflicts.

> I tried to use `RewriteRule` (old URL to new URL) instead of `RedirectPermanent` as recommanded in old questions but it has the exact same effect.

That sounds like you are seeing a cached response from the earlier `RedirectPermanent` directive (301s are cached persistently by the browser). If the correct `RewriteRule` is placed before the above rewrite it would work as intended. If you placed it after then it wouldn't do anything since the URL-path will not match.

> (From comments)
>
> ```
>  RewriteRule /page-320-enfants /page-2028-pour-les-invitees [R=301,L]
> ```

This rule seems to be in the right place (before the internal rewrite), however, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (1st argument) is incorrect and will not match the requested URL, so the rule does nothing.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (a regex) matches against the URL-path after the directory-prefix (the file-path to the `.htaccess` file) has been removed. The directory-prefix always ends with a slash, so the URL-path that is matched never starts with a slash. So this rule should be written like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^page-320-enfants$ /page-2028-pour-les-invitees [R=301,L]
```

To redirect from `/page-320-enfants` to `/page-2028-pour-les-invitees`

**UPDATE:**

> (From updated question)
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^page-2028-pour-les-invitees$ page-320-enfants [R=301,L]
> ```

Ok, you've removed the slash prefix, however, you seem to have switched the from/to and have omitted the *necessary* slash prefix on the *substitution* string (2nd argument)!?

Assuming you want to redirect *from* `/page-320-enfants` then this should appear on the left (first argument).

The issue with no slash prefix on the *substitution* string (and no `RewriteBase` directive) is that the directory-prefix will be added back and expose the server's file-path in the external redirect - in other words, the redirect would be malformed (if it occurred at all).

Comment: Its working ! So it actually was a matter of a misplaced slash. Thanks a lot for your help and the precise explanation on how the process works.